# Memoization with a closure example from Land of Lisp

Tags: common-lisp, memoization, land-of-lisp

On page 329 of *Land of Lisp*, Conrad Barski explains the technique of *memoization* with the following example code

```
(let ((old-neighbors (symbol-function 'neighbors))
      (previous (make-hash-table)))
  (defun neighbors (pos)
    (or (gethash pos previous)
        (setf (gethash pos previous) (funcall old-neighbors pos)))))
```

The idea is nice: when I call the `neighbors` function, I save the result into a hash table, so that the next time calling `neighbors` with the same value of `pos`, I can just look-up the result without having to compute it again.

So I was wondering, whether it would not be easier to rename the function `neighbors` to `old-neighbors` by editing and recompiling its source code (given on page 314 of the book). Then the memoization example could be simplified to

```
(let ((previous (make-hash-table)))
  (defun neighbors (pos)
    (or (gethash pos previous)
        (setf (gethash pos previous) (funcall old-neighbors pos)))))
```

or, by turning `previous` into a global variable `*previous-neighbors*` beforehand, even into

```
(defun neighbors (pos)
  (or (gethash pos *previous-neighbors*)
      (setf (gethash pos *previous-neighbors*) (funcall old-neighbors pos))))
```

thus rendering the closure unnecessary.

So my **question** is: what is the reason for doing it this way?

Reasons I could imagine:

1. It's didactical, showing what could be done with a closure (which had been explained just before) and providing an example of `symbol-function`.
2. This technique is applicable even in situations, where you cannot or may not change the source code of `neighbors`.
3. I am missing something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have made some good observations.

Generally the style to use closures like that is more likely to be found in Scheme code - where Scheme developers often use functions to return functions.

Generally as you have detected it makes little sense to have a memoize function `foo` calling an function `old-foo`. Using global variables reduces *encapsulation* (-> *information hiding*), but increases the ability to *debug* a program, since one can more easily inspect the memoized values.

A similar, but potentially more useful, pattern would be this:

```
(defun foo (bar)
  <does some expensive computation>)

(memoize 'foo)
```

Where ˋmemoizeˋ would be something like this

```
(defun memoize (symbol)
  (let ((original-function (symbol-function symbol))
        (values            (make-hash-table)))
    (setf (symbol-function symbol)
          (lambda (arg &rest args)
            (or (gethash arg values)
                (setf (gethash arg values)
                      (apply original-function arg args)))))))
```

The advantage is that you don't need to write the memoizing code for each function. You only need one function `memoize`. In this case the closure also makes sense - though you could also have a global table storing memoize tables.

Note the limitations of above: the comparison uses `EQL` and only the first argument of the function to memoize.

There are also more extensive tools to provide similar functionality.

See for example:

- https://github.com/fare/fare-memoization
- https://github.com/sharplispers/cormanlisp/blob/master/examples/memoize.lisp
- https://github.com/AccelerationNet/function-cache

Using my `memoize` from above:

```
CL-USER 22 > (defun foo (n)
               (sleep 3)
               (expt 2 n))
FOO

CL-USER 23 > (memoize 'foo)
#<Closure 1 subfunction of MEMOIZE 40600008EC>
```

The first call with arg `10` runs three seconds:

```
CL-USER 24 > (foo 10)
1024
```

The second call with arg `10` runs faster:

```
CL-USER 25 > (foo 10)
1024
```

The first call with arg `2` runs three seconds:

```
CL-USER 26 > (foo 2)
4
```

The second call with arg `2` runs faster:

```
CL-USER 27 > (foo 2)
4
```

The third call with arg `10` runs fast:

```
CL-USER 28 > (foo 10)
1024
```

Comment: Reading a bit further, I came across an idea similar to the approach you suggest in Paul Graham's On Lisp, Figure 5.2. But I find your version easier to use, because one needs to call

    (memoize 'foo)
    (foo 10)

whereas the other one would be called with something like

    (setq fast-foo (memoize 'foo))
    (funcall fast-foo 10)

Are there any further differences apart from this and using
    equal
instead of
    eql
for comparisons?